# queryset para traer registros menos a uno en especifico

Tags: python, django

Tengo una vista basada en clases en la cual tengo una funcion que realiza una consulta en uno de los modelos:

```
    def get_sympatizers_to_reference(self):
        if self.request.GET.get('q'):
            self.q = self.request.GET.get('q')
            s = Simpatizante.objects.filter(num_documento__contains=self.q).first()
            return [s] if s else None
        else:
            return None
```

este queryset trae todos los registros del modelo que coinciden con la cadena ingresada en un input, mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para que no traiga a un registro en especifico en la consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer un exclude por ejemplo:

```
def get_sympatizers_to_reference(self):
    if self.request.GET.get('q'):
        self.q = self.request.GET.get('q')
        s = 
Simpatizante.objects.filter(num_documento__contains=self.q).exclude(id=5).first()
        return [s] if s else None
    else:
        return None
```

O puedes importar Q y hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
from django.db.models import Q
def get_sympatizers_to_reference(self):
    if self.request.GET.get('q'):
        self.q = self.request.GET.get('q')
        s = Simpatizante.objects.filter(~Q(id=5), num_documento__contains=self.q).first()
        return [s] if s else None
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: muchas gracias @Roberto, con el exclude me funciono perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es que no devuelva un registro específico, esto es, un solo registro, sino que traiga **todos los registros que contengan esa cadena** ingresada, simplemente quita el `first()`. *First* en inglés significa primero, y hace que tu `queryset` devuelva un solo registro, el primero. 
Prueba entonces con:

```
s =  Simpatizante.objects.filter(num_documento__contains=self.q)
```

Por otra parte, el método `filter` trae muchos registros por esto devuelve una lista. No hace falta entonces que `s` este dentro de una lista nueva como hiciste:

```
return [s] if s else None
```

podés directamente hacer:

```
return s if s else None
```

Comment: Hola @eduzen, tienes razón con lo que dices acerca del método `first()`, yo lo tenia implementado por que asi lo necesitaba y al utilizar este método por obligación me tocaba convertir el resultado de la consulta en una lista `[s]` si no me arrojaba un error, ahora que ya el requerimiento cambio quite el `first()` y cambie el return por `return s if s else None`

Comment: Perfecto @MauricioVilla buenisimo que empezaste a usar el `first()`. Saludos!